# Highlight text using query value in Griddle table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, griddle

I have data in griddle table. I am entering search string through custom filter box. I want to highlight search string value in griddle columns . How is it possible ? I want to achieve this in react`<code>https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/buh9h2r8/"</code>`

Comment: You could do it with [mark.js](https://markjs.io/)

Comment: I tried it but it is not working for me. May you give any link or piece of code for reference ? I will be thankful.

Comment: I could do that if YOU do that.

Comment: I have done this in jquery.But in react it is not working.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: @PankajArora were you able to find a way to do this. Can  you please post the code

Comment: I want to achieve this in react https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/buh9h2r8/

Comment: @user3067170 I couldn't find the solution yet